# How to search a list element, STL C++

Tags: c++, stl

I havd a problem with my code. I have class named CPerson.

```
class CPerson {
private:
    string name;
    string lastName;
    int age;
    char *pPesel;

public:

    CPerson( string i, string n, int w,   char *pPes);
...
};
```

I have a list.

```
list <CPerson> lst;

list <CPerson> ::iterator it;
it = lst.begin(); 

CPerson wzor1("John", "Steward", 22, "2323"  );
```

When i fill it up, i want find an CPerson instance whose `lastName` field begins, for example, with "Kow".

Is it possible to make that "Kow" as a parameter to the any function?

I was trying with `find` or `find_if` but it never worked, dont know how to write a predicate, any ideas?

Comment: I can add all code, but it is unnecessary because i have a problem only with function find_if..

Comment: Slight detour: don’t put a `C` in front of class names, there’s no good reason for this. The convention started as a misunderstanding and is useless.

Comment: After filling up the list, do you want the object(s) whose lastname member is "Kow" ?

Comment: What problem do you have? You should at least show enough code to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A predicate is like a call back function on each element while iterating over the container.

```
bool VerifyLastName( CPerson& obj )
{
    return (obj.getLastName() == "Kow");
}

std::list<CPerson>::iterator it = std::find_if(lst.begin(), lst.end(), VerifyLastName);
```

If `it` is not equal to the `lst.end()`, then iterator is pointing to the object with the member whose last name  is "Kow".

Answer (score 1):

```
//Create a member function getLastName in your class
std::string CPerson::getLastName( void ){
return lastname;
}

//Create a function object for find_if use.
struct checkLastName{
    checkLastName(const std::string & test):checkName(test){}
    bool operator()( CPerson& ob ){
        return ob.getLastName().substr(0, checkName.size()).compare(checkName);
    }
    std::string checkName;
};

std::string lname;
cin>>lname; //"Kow"

//Use std::find_if
std::list<CPerson>::iterator it = 
             std::find_if(lst.begin(), 
                  lst.end(), checkLastName(lname)); 

if(it!=lst.end())
    std::cout<<" Found ";
```

With C++11, you can use lambda function as:

```
std::list<CPerson>::iterator it = 
          std::find_if(lst.begin(), 
                       lst.end(), 
                  [lname](CPerson const& ob){
                  return ob.getLastName().substr(0, lname.size()).compare(lname);
                                 }));
```

Comment: bool operator ( CPerson& ob )

Comment: what i thought :), and if(it!=list.end()) - should be if(it!=lst.end()) ? and i don't know what does it mean - "lst.end() - it;", i must overload next operator "-" ?

Comment: Rather than adding a member function to ask for last name then testing it externally. Why not add a member function for checking a constraint (like is the last name XXXX). That is more flexible and maintains better encapsulation.

Comment: OK thanks, but if i write std::cout<<*it instead this line- std::cout<<Found "; , i see first element on a list, but not this, which i search("Kow")..

Comment: The iterator is running on list of `CPerson` objects, `it` searches the object that has "Kow" as `lastname`, you need to write function to see the data members.

Comment: CPerson wzor1   ("John",    "Steward"    , 22    , "2323"  );  CPerson wzor1    ("John", "Morris", 22, "2323" );      this is my list, and when i write "Mor" in cin>>lastname i get info about John Steward.. i'm trying to write this funtion.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use of find_if is shown in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/ with a simple predicate function (IsOdd). To add an argument you are probably better off using a function object (functor) or bind1st on a binary function http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/bind1st/.

If you are using C++11 you can use a lambda/anonymous function.